# Wrong average after third input

Tags: c#

Hey Guys, I am writing a performance monitor program that keeps track of different things, one of them being the Memory Available. I have been able to use this same code to find out the min,max, and average for the other Performance Counters, but this one keeps giving me the wrong Average.

The first average is correct, then I get really low numbers. So lets say the first two times i got 1500MB and 1400MB free Average would be 1450MB, then third time is 1600MB, then my output for Average would be something in the 700-800MB.

If you can please point me to the right direction, that would be appreciated! Thanks :)

```
        //Move to and get the latest value in the performance counter for Memory Available Bytes
        m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes = perfMemoryBytes.NextValue();

        //Increase the count that will be used to divide the sum to get average
        iCount++;

        m.TotalMemoryAvailableBytes += m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes;

        //Check if the current value is greater then the max for memory available bytes
        if (m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes > m.MaxMemoryAvailableBytes)
            m.MaxMemoryAvailableBytes = m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes;

        //Initialize Min so its not stuck at 0
        if (iCount == 1)
        {
            m.MinMemoryAvailableBytes = m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes;
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if the current value is less then the min for memory available bytes
            if (m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes < m.MinMemoryAvailableBytes)
                m.MinMemoryAvailableBytes = m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes;
        }
        addListView("Memory Available Bytes", Convert.ToInt16(m.CurrentMemoryAvailableBytes / 1048576),
            Convert.ToInt16((m.TotalMemoryAvailableBytes / iCount) / 1048576), Convert.ToInt16(m.MinMemoryAvailableBytes / 1048576),
            Convert.ToInt16(m.MaxMemoryAvailableBytes / 1048576));
```

Here is an output example:

Sunday, 24/10/2010 02:49:10 PM

Type    Last    Average Min Max

Memory  1319MB  1319MB  1319MB  1319MB

Sunday, 24/10/2010 02:49:40 PM

Type    Last    Average Min Max

Memory  1326MB  442MB   0MB 1326MB

Comment: Why would the average of 1400 and 1500 be 14500 rather than 1450?

Comment: Your output shows the Min going to 0... which suggests you've been collecting at least *one* value of 0, so it's not surprising that the average has dropped. Again, if you could provide a short but complete program, that would help... You might also want to look at the Math.Max and Math.Min methods to avoid your if statements.

Comment: That is puzzling me also, I inserted the if(iCount == 1) there for that reason alone, to remove the default zero that shows up as I start the program. But I clearly need to look into that more in depth, because that seems to be the problem.

Comment: if the problem happens often then save all values in array for debugging purposes and when the strange behavior occurs look at those values in debugger. This will give you more info. Maybe there is no bug after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're storing the total number of bytes in a `uint`, and it's overflowing... or something like that, anyway. It's quite hard to tell without more code. Overflow is an obvious candidate when numbers that you're adding up suddenly become small.

If you could write a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make it a lot easier to tell what the problem really is though.

It's not clear to me why you're calling `Convert.ToInt16` either though - why would you want to limit your information like that?

Comment: I got it thanks. The answer wasn't in this post, but one of the comments of the original answer. The if statement that I was using was incorrect, when removed, it would output the correct average. Will look into other ways of initializing the min to the correct value. Thanks again!